# How do I set edit permissions for other users while sharing a document

Tags: google-drive, permissions, google-drive-sharing

I share a Google doc with UserA, UserB, UserC. I want administrators AdminA, AdminB or would preferably would like to have a group GroupA comprising the two administrators to have the ability to set Share permissions on the document.

Currently the Share permissions can be set by anyone who I am sharing the document with, this is a security problem for us.

How do we set the permissions correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1**

When sharing, the default setting is to allow anyone who has **Edit** rights to also **Share** the document.

When you open the share window, you should see some small text at the bottom that says:

"Editors will be allowed to add people and change the permissions. [Change]"

Click on change, and then change the setting to "Only the owner can change the permissions"

**Part 2**

Now that only you can change permissions of a doc, you'll need to change AdminA and AdminB **from** "Can edit" **to** "Is Owner"

This will allow them to manage the permissions on a doc as well.

As for allowing a group alias' members to have edit/owner/sharing permissions, that will need to be addressed in your other question about Group Permissions.

Comment: In my case I have 40 editors for whom editing option is given and I want to change the permission for all users to "View" only. How can I do it?